# Extend template for js inclusion

Tags: javascript, include, smarty

i have a web project. The project is based on Smarty templates.
I have a base.tpl with the common structure, for all pages of my site.

The base.tpl have the next line, thats includes the template requested by the user:

```
{include file="{$request}"}
```

For example. When the user request `http://mydomain/contact`, $request have "contact.tpl" value.

And the bottom of base template have the inclusion of the commons js files:

```
{block name="javascript"}
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/common.js"></script>
{/block}
```

So, any templates requested by the user, requires the inclusion of mores javascript files, that i like insert in the "javascript" block.

I try, for example in the contact.tpl the next code:

```
{block name="javascript" prepend}
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/validation/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/contact.js"></script>
{/block}
```

But, the files not load in the browser. Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a method that has served me. I define in my controller (php script) the paths to js, in an array.
In the tpl, iterate the "array of paths" and include the files.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works, the blocks are not processed simply by including a file. It should be something like:

base.tpl:

```
<html>
  <head>
{block name="javascript"}
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/common.js"></script>
{/block}
  </head>
  <body>
  {block name="contents"}{/block}
  </body>
</html>
```

contact.tpl:

```
{extends file="base.tpl"} 
{block name="javascript" prepend}
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/libs/validation/localization/messages_es.js"></script>
    <script src="{$BASE_URL}/assets/js/contact.js"></script>
{/block}
{block name="contents"}
Your contact form here
{/block}
```

Check [Smarty's Template Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl) for more information

Comment: I like include the scripts inmediatly before at body end tag. it is not possible with smarty?

Comment: of course. Just move the {block name="javascript"} in base.tpl where you want